# Error when running grunt sass compile task

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have the following error when running a grunt task to compile a scss file:

```
Running "watch:sass" (watch) task
Waiting...
>> File "Content\sass\main.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Error: expected "{".
@import "layout";
                ^
  Content\sass\main.scss 4:17  root stylesheet
Warning: Exited with error code 65 Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

The sass file (main.scss) contains one line of code:

```
@import "layout";
```

And the layout file has a simple few lines of CSS.

The problem I'm having with this is that I have run this exact same config with the exact same code on different machines before without fail; the issue must be with this computer.

When I run node -v, I get v8.11.2. When I run npm -v, I get v5.6.0

I'm running a new install of Windows 10 using Visual Studio to code and command line to run the tasks.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "SafeOnlineMVC",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

My gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-sass");

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: "compressed"
                },
                files: [
                  {
                      "Content/main.css": "Content/sass/main.scss"
                  }
                ]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ["Content/sass/*.scss"],
                tasks: ["sass"]
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks.

Edit: Main scss file:

```
@import "_layout";
```

Edit: Layout scss file:

```
.inner{
    width: 1320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `main.scss` and `layout.scss`?

Comment: Sure, have included. It's as basic as it gets though. I've tried saving the file with and without the underscore just in case (and updated the main scss accordingly)

Comment: Are you using a fresh install of the npm modules? You could try force the reinstallation of grunt-contrib-sass

Comment: It was all fresh installs yes. Force reinstall of grunt-contrib-sass didn't work but I could perhaps reinstall everything from scratch. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: As `grunt-contrib-sass` uses the Ruby gem to compile sass, did you tried compile the scss with the gem directly? Just to discard a gem or ruby issue: run `sass main.scss main.css` in `Content/sass`

Answer (score -2):

There is an error in your css, as indicated by the error message. You're missing an opening brace after a selector name.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case. I've tested with various css and even an empty file. No matter what I do, I still get the same issue. But as soon as I copy the files over to my old development machine, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting your css. There is indeed an error in it.

Comment: No, that is not an error. Test it. There is nothing wrong with not leaving a blank space between selectors and curly brackets.

Comment: Sorry Seth but there is no css error. If you read my reply you'll notice I said I use the exact same css on a different machine without fail (using the same sass/npm/node versions).